# Haproxy and HTTPS

Tags: docker, https, haproxy

Hey guys I have my first project at my first job ever. It's about dockerinzing a NodeJs app and running it locally. I did the dockerinzing and it runs on HTTP. But I don't know how to run in on HTTPS and as a note I must use 'DOCKER' and 'Terminal' to do this job. Knowing that I already have a file which contains the certification.pem.

My Dockerfile looks like this :

```
##############################
# OS
##############################
FROM debian:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

##############################
# Tools
##############################
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y wget nano curl

##############################
# Haproxy
##############################
RUN apt-get install -y haproxy

##############################
# PORTS
##############################
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

**And my Docker-compose.yml** looks like this : 

version: "2"

###########################################
services:
###########################################

  #######################
  haproxy:
  #######################
    build:
      context: ./services/haproxy/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    stdin_open: true  #docker run -i
    tty: true         #docker run -t
    volumes:
      - "./services/haproxy/bootstrap.sh:/bootstrap.sh"
      - "./volumes/haproxy/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg"
      - haproxy_ssl:/etc/haproxy/ssl
    entrypoint: sh -c "/bootstrap.sh"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      vlan:

  #######################
  mariadb:
  #######################
    build:
      context: ./services/mariadb/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    #container_name: mariadb
    volumes:
      - mariadb_sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=toor
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      vlan:

  ######################
  frontend:
  ######################
    build:
      context: ./services/frontend/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    #restart: always
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true        # docker run -t
    volumes:
      - frontend_src:/src
      - "./services/frontend/bootstrap.sh:/bootstrap.sh"
    entrypoint: sh -c "/bootstrap.sh"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      vlan:

###########################################
volumes:
###########################################
  frontend_src: 
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: ./volumes/frontend/src
  mariadb_sql: 
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: ./volumes/mariadb/sql
  haproxy_ssl: 
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: ./volumes/haproxy/ssl

########################################      
networks:
########################################
  vlan:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      parent: eth0
    #ipam:
    #  config:
    #    - subnet: "10.10.3.0/24"
    #      ip_range: "10.10.3.64/26"
    #      gateway: "10.10.3.1"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is here.

Comment: It's about how can i enable HTTPS in this case

Comment: It's about running this website locally on HTTPS using haproxy and docker terminal , i don't have any idea about how to do it at all